# Parsing xml. return one object not collection

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file:

```
  <Result>Ok</Result>
  <Error></Error>
  <Remark></Remark>
  <Data>
    <Movies>
      <Movie ID='2'>
        <Name><![CDATA[TestName]]></Name>
        <Duration Duration='170'>2h 50min</Duration>            
        <Properties>
          <Property Name='11'><![CDATA[1111110]]></Property>
        </Properties>
        <Rental from_date='' to_date=''>
          <SessionCount></SessionCount>
          <PU_NUMBER></PU_NUMBER>
        </Rental>
      </Movie>
    </Movies>
  </Data>
</XML>
```

Code for pasring xml file:

```
var results = from element in XDocument.Parse(queryResponse).Descendants("Movie")
                          select new BaseEvent
                          {
                              OID = (int)element.Attribute("ID"),
                              Subject = (string)element.Element("Name"),
                              Duration = (int)element.Element("Duration").Attribute("Duration")
                          };
```

The problem in that `Descedants` retruns `IEumerable<BaseEvent>` but I want that will be `BaseEvent`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `First()`, `Last()`, `Single()`, `FirstOrDefault()` etc.

Personally I'd do that *initially*, rather than doing it all in a query:

```
var element = XDocument.Parse(queryResponse)
                       .Descendants("Movie")
                       .FirstOrDefault();
if (element == null)
{
    // Handle the case of no movies
}
else
{
    var baseEvent = new BaseEvent
                    {
                        OID = (int) element.Attribute("ID"),
                        Subject = (string) element.Element("Name"),
                        Duration = (int) element.Element("Duration")
                                                .Attribute("Duration")
                    };
    // Use baseEvent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `.First()` to get the first element:

```
from element in XDocument.Parse(queryResponse).Descendants("Movie")
                          select new BaseEvent
                          {
                              OID = (int)element.Attribute("ID"),
                              Subject = (string)element.Element("Name"),
                              Duration = (int)element.Element("Duration").Attribute("Duration")
                          }.First();
```

You can alternatively use `FirstOrDefault()` (in case there are no such nodes), `Last()` or `Single()`.